# Mixing Voltages to get a bigger one?

Tags: power-supply

It must sound like a really idiotic question but i am just a novice in electronics, i have two 5v phone chargers that i would LOVE to use to feed a 9v project instead of a 9v battery but i want to know if it will... You know... **EXPLODE** if i mix their output cables in any way, is there a way to do this? Maybe if i rectify them with diodes? Maybe up-step them so they will give a bigger voltage? I DONT KNOW YOU CAN INSULT ME IF YOU REALLY NEED TO, BUT HELP ME, the project is a guitar amplifier

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=boost+switching+regulator

Comment: Why would you need to rectify a 5VDC power supply? Whatever, the answer is spend the $5-$10 on a single 9v wall-wart or seek out a decent power-supply rather than doing some ugly dumb kludge.

Answer (score 3):

While some regulators are designed to be able to be put in series, most are not. Given that you have two generic no-name 5v/usb phone chargers, that's not the right way to go in any case.

You could break one open, and hope for a clean board with labels, or a common regulator IC without it's markings removed, so you can look for a datasheet. Most of the time, the charger manufacturer goes with the reference design suggested by the regulator's manufacturer, making it easy to modify, but sometimes not.

The best case scenario would be to use an external boost regulator circuit, to bring that 5v up to 9v. You would want to choose high quality capacitors to minimize noise, as with a music oriented device like your amp, would not be ideal. Since it is designed for a 9v battery, current is not the concern, just the voltage. **Or simply buying a 9v power supply designed for audio systems, to avoid any noise issues.**

Comment: Careful with the 9V power supply, as any ripple will work its way into the audio.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that's why I recommended it be one designed for audio devices, instead of any old 9v adaptor.

Answer (score 2):

Most phone chargers take the AC power, convert to DC, switch the dc up and down (at a high frequency) and feed that switched voltage through an isolation transformer. At the output of the transformer, the signal is converted back to DC and usually regulated to 5V or some other DC voltage.

Note that the output is isolated from the input due to the use of a transformer.

More traditional chargers/adapters use a power AC transformer and use this to step down the voltage whereapon it is rectifed, smoothed and possibly fed to a voltage regulator.

Note that the output is isolated from the input due to the use of a transformer.

In both cases you can usually get two chargers and wire the output voltages in series. If the output is 5V, when wired in series you get 10V.

This isn't 9V but will quite probably work for what the OP intends. However, one warning - the outputs may need additional filtering to prevent noise getting into the amplifier. It's possibly worth trying and then deciding.